# Crystal Reports Version Conflict

Tags: iis-7, crystal-reports, windows-server-2008

I developed a web app that creates crystal reports with VS Crystal report version 13.0.2000.0. I tried publishing it and putting it in the wwwroot folder (IIS7). When I run it, it give me this error:

> Parse Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDescision.Web, Version 13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file.
>
> Source Error:
>
> <% Register Assembly="CrystalDecision.Web Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"

When I run the command `%windir%\assembly` on the server, the version is 10.5.3700.

My questions is which crystal report should I download/buy to upgrade my server crystal reports? Because there was many links on the SAP website (ie. Crystal Report, Crystal Report Server, Crystal Report Viewer, and more).

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the Crystal Reports 2010 runtime (Redist Installation package) on the computer that you are having trouble? The 13.0 version is CR for VS 2010 and you can download the runtime here

http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/weblogs?blog=/pub/wlg/22083

Answer (score -1):

It is all about different version.
Remove the references to Crystal*.* and right click on References to add the correct ones

Assemblies, Extensions

You will see everything installed on you computer environment.

Select the ones with the same version that is on your web.config

Make sure the versions on web.config match the whole fu..ing s.it

This is a pain on the ass brought to you by Crystal Reports !